# Display an image using PySimpleGUI and get coordinates of mouse click

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Suppose I have an image named 'image.jpg'. I want to be able to display this image using PySimpleGUI and get the pixel coordinate values of a mouse click on the displayed image.

I have looked in many places on the internet but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With `Graph` element, you can set option `enable_events=True` to generate event when click, also method `draw_image` to place an image onto the canvas.

Refer https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#graph-element

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

size = (320, 240)
image = sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_BIG_SMILE

layout = [
    [sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, enable_events=True, key='-GRAPH-')],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-GRAPH-':
        x, y = values[event]
        location = (x-28, y+28)     # figure size is (56, 56)
        # Using option `filename` if the image source is a file
        window['-GRAPH-'].draw_image(data=image, location=location)

window.close()
```

[image]